# Сортировка слиянием в C++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Мне нужно отсортировать массив по возрастанию сортировкой слияния. Мне нужно, чтобы он считывал из файла sort.in из первой строки количество элементов массива, а из второй - сами элементы. Дальше он их сортирует и выводит отсортированный массив в файл sort.out. Он выдает ошибку при этом коде.
Заранее неизвестно количество элементов массива, я могу ввести любое количество и он должен это количество считать.

````
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//функция, сливающая массивы
void Merge(int* A, int first, int last) {
    int middle, start, final, j;
    int* mas = new int[1000];
    middle = (first + last) / 2;  //вычисление среднего элемента
    start = first;                //начало левой части
    final = middle + 1;           //начало правой части
    for (j = first; j <= last; j++)  //выполнять от начала до конца
        if ((start <= middle) && ((final > last) || (A[start] < A[final]))) {
            mas[j] = A[start];
            start++;
        }
        else {
            mas[j] = A[final];
            final++;
        }
    //возвращение результата в список
    for (j = first; j <= last; j++)
        A[j] = mas[j];
    delete[] mas;
};
//рекурсивная процедура сортировки
void MergeSort(int* A, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        MergeSort(A, first, (first + last) / 2);  //сортировка левой части
        MergeSort(A, (first + last) / 2 + 1, last);  //сортировка правой части
        Merge(A, first, last);  //слияние двух частей
    }
}
//главная функция
void main() {
    int n;//количество элементов массива
    ifstream in("sort.in");
    ofstream out("sort.out");
    in >> n;
    int* A = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        in >> A[i];
    }
    MergeSort(A, 1, n);  //вызов сортирующей процедуры
    //вывод упорядоченного массива
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        out << A[i] << " ";
    delete[] A;
    system("pause>>void");
}```
````

Comment: `"Он выдает ошибку при этом коде"` -- укажите, где именно и какую.

Answer (score 1):

`ввести любое количество` и `mas = new int[1000];` как-то не очень сочетаются...

Вот этот цикл со слишком сложным условием:

```
 for (j = first; j <= last; j++)  //выполнять от начала до конца
        if ((start <= middle) && ((final > last) || (A[start] < A[final]))) {
            mas[j] = A[start];
            start++;
        }
        else {
            mas[j] = A[final];
            final++;
        }
```

Отлаживать и понимать тяжело. Навскидку, например, я, как Ферми с проектом АЭС, не вижу, что будет, если вторая часть исчерпается раньше. Похоже, что бадабум, т.е. выход за границу массива

По классике делается три цикла while - [вот как здесь](http://algolist.manual.ru/sort/merge_sort.php), только в сравнении меньше или равно надо поставить `if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2])`